# Servelet response.sendRedirect(url) does not update URL in browser

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect

I'm encountering an Issue when Trying to redirect from one JSP Page to another using a Servlet. The rquested page will be loaded but the URL will stay on the Controllers URL.

JSP call:

```
    <a href="../MobileZuDesktopController" class="ui-btn">Desktop Version</a>
```

This JSP file is under webapp/mobile/index.jsp  while the target is /webapp/index.jsp .
I'm using response.sendRedirect("index.jsp") to redirect the request, after adding a flag to the Session.

```
    public class MobileZuDesktopController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String url = "index.jsp";
private HttpSession session;



public MobileZuDesktopController() {
    super();

}
public void init(ServletConfig conf) throws ServletException  {
    super.init(conf);
}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("UseristMobile", 0);
    System.out.println(session.getAttribute("UseristMobile"));
    response.sendRedirect(url);

}
```

After the redirect the CorrectPage "index.jsp" is loaded but the URL of the Browser is still webapp/MobileZuDesktopController  and the CSS of the former page is still active, after a reload of the Page the URL updates to webapp/index.jsp and the correct CSS is loaded.

I can't find the Issue with this setup and according to all the resources I could find the sendRedirect() function should have the desired effect. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: This is a consequence of the browser, not of servlet technology.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Is there anything I can do to force the new URL for the browser?